# Query Mean js with form,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, meanjs

Good evening,

I want to make a search engine for an application in JS MEAN.

I have a database with different elements and want to fill out a form and have the result of all the elements in a different view.

I have not tried a lot , I read but I have not seen anything concrete that can help.

How can I pass the search parameters to the controller of the client, then the controller server and have the results in a different view ?

Ohn attempt to search by type , color and from a date to another .

All these data already stored in the database .

Can someone help me with a simple example of the transaction between the search form, client controller and server controller?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need an answer. I'll explain a little bit. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/hibernator11/Galatea):

```
<section ng-controller="BooklistPaginationController" ng-init="init(10)">

....
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<div id="filter-panel" class="filter-panel" collapse="searchIsCollapsed">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="filter-col" for="pref-search">Texto:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="pref-search" ng-model="text">
    </div><!-- form group [search] -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="filter-col" for="pref-orderby">Orden:</label>
    <select id="pref-orderby" class="form-control" ng-model="order">
    <option ng-repeat="x in optionsOrder" value="{{x.value}}">{{x.text}}</option>
    </select> 
    </div> <!-- form group [order by] --> 
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="filter-col" for="pref-perpage">Elementos página:</label>
    <select id="pref-perpage" class="form-control" ng-model="itemsPerPage">
    <option ng-repeat="x in optionsItemsPage" value="{{x.value}}">{{x.text}}</option>
    </select> 
    </div> <!-- form group [rows] -->
    <button ng-click="find()" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top: 4px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar
    </button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the view. You can see the form html tag and you can search by text using an order and pagination. We also need the controller and you can see how you can call the server in order to perform the search.

```
angular.module('booklists').controller('BooklistPaginationController',     ['$scope', 'Booklists',
function ($scope, Booklists) {

$scope.searchIsCollapsed = true;

$scope.optionsItemsPage = [
    {text : "10", value : "10"},
    {text : "30", value : "30"},
    {text : "50", value : "50"}
];

$scope.optionsOrder = [
    {text : "Descendente", value : "asc"},
    {text : "Ascendente", value : "desc"}
];

$scope.optionsStatus = [
    {text : "Todos", value : ""},
    {text : "Borrador", value : "draft"},
    {text : "Publicado", value : "public"}
];

$scope.init = function(itemsPerPage){
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.status = 'public';
    $scope.order = 'desc';
    $scope.find();
};

$scope.pageChanged = function () {
    $scope.find();
};

$scope.find = function () {

    var query = { page:$scope.currentPage,
                  itemsPerPage:$scope.itemsPerPage,
                  order:$scope.order,
                  status:$scope.status,
                  text:$scope.text
                };

    Booklists.query(query, function (data) {
        $scope.pagedItems = data[0].booklists;
        $scope.total = data[0].total;
    });
};
}
]);
```